# Pass SSIS variable to Process task

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

How to pass variables defined in SSIS as parameters to SSIS Process task that runs a bat file.

In the bat file the user name and password would be replaced with %1 argument and input will be passed from the script task that will receive input from a .NET front-end.

Please do help with screenshots if possible

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the script task, write the value to a SSIS variable.

In the Exec Process task, modify the Arguments expression, to pass the variable into the task

There is a screenshot on this thread [How to execute a Process Task where the Executable path comes from a user Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818398/how-to-execute-a-process-task-where-the-executable-path-comes-from-a-user-variab)

Comment: screen shots no longer available